# How to remove words added by mistake from spelling check?

Tags: dictionary, linguistics

In text mode, I mistakenly add a word `exx` to the dictionary, which makes it impossible to check the spelling of this word. What can I do to delete only the mistakenly added word from the dictionary?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `CurrentValue` to find the words that have been added to the dictionary for all notebooks:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {SpellingDictionaries, "CorrectWords"}]

(* {"MyCompany", "AnotherCompany", "exx"} *)
```

We can update the dictionary by assigning a new list to this expression.  This could be a completely new list or, as in the following example, we might delete just a single word:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {SpellingDictionaries, "CorrectWords"}] =
  DeleteCases[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {SpellingDictionaries, "CorrectWords"}], "exx"]

(* {"MyCompany", "AnotherCompany"} *)
```

Words can also be added or removed from the dictionary associated with a particular notebook by replacing `$FrontEnd` in these expressions with `EvaluationNotebook[]` or any other notebook reference.

Reference: [Add Words to the Spelling Dictionary](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/AddWordsToTheSpellingDictionary.html).