# Adding spelling dictionary to Mathematica

Tags: front-end, options, files-and-directories, dictionary, spellchecker

I was hoping this could be easy, but it's not. I need to add the Czech spelling dictionary to Mathematica.

1. I copied the two files: cs_CZ.aff and cs_CZ.dic in to the /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Components/SpellingData
2. I opened the file "SpellingData.m" and added there the "Czech" -> "cs_CZ" like it's done with other languages.
3. I went into the Option inspector and Global Options -> System configuration -> Dictionaries and added there the necessary associations.

However, I still cannot make it work, i.e. it still underlines everything red when I write in Czech.

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239113/how-to-remove-words-added-by-mistake-from-spelling-check) is a similar question.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need adding individual words, it's rather how to get. Mathematica to realise there is a Czech dictionary. Because the language is not offered in the Option inspector -> Formatting options -> Text content options -> Default natural language.

Answer (score 2):

After contacting Wolfarm support, I got the following answer:

*"Hello Jiri,
Our developers have confirmed that it is not possible to add other languages in Mathematica.
However, I have filed a suggestion report to include a feature that would enable users to add other languages in future versions of Mathematica.
If you have any further questions, please do not hesitate to contact us."*